Derivative of $x^TA$
Let be $A$ an $n\times n$ matrix and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then wikipedia and the books say that the derivative of $f(x):=x^TA$ is $A^T$.
I was trying to apply this result to the official definition of differentiability i.e.
$f$ is differentiable in $a$ if there exists a linear mapping $B$ such that
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{\Vert x^T-a^TA-B(x-a)\Vert}{\Vert x-a\Vert}=0.
$$

If I try $B=A^T$ then the nomiator is not well defined due to different dimensions. However, if I take the rows of $A^T$ and convert them into a $1\times n$ vector where the $i$-th row is located in the $i$-th entry of the $1\times n$ vector, then it works.
So my question is: Instead of saying that $A^T$ is the dervitative would it be "more" correct to say that the above constructed $1\times n$ vector is the derivative? Or how do I make sense of the commonly known statement that $A^T$ is the derivative?

You are wright, $A^T$ is not strictly speaking the derivative of $f$, but it is the derivative of $g$ such that $g(x)=(f(x))^T=A^Tx$.

It's the Jacobian of the vector-valued function. In the literature, there are two ways to write the Jacobian, which are transpose to each other. To derive the result, you can start from $\partial f_i/\partial x_j$

A lot of the confusion in this question can be cleared by writing $y^\intercal=x^\intercal A$. From this it is clear that $dy=A^\intercal dx$.

If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and we view $\mathbb R^n$ as $\mathrm{Mat}_{n,1}(\mathbb R)$, i.e. as the space of $n\times 1$ column vectors, then $x\mapsto x^\intercal A$ defines a map
$$
f\colon \mathbb R^n:=\mathrm{Mat}_{n,1}(\mathbb R) \to \mathrm{Mat}_{1,n}(\mathbb R)
$$
Let us write $(\mathbb R^n)^*$ for $\mathrm{Mat}_{1,n}(\mathbb R)$.
Now by definition, the derivative $Df_a$ of $f$ at $a\in \mathbb R^n$ must be a linear map $\alpha\colon \mathbb R^n \to (\mathbb R^n)^*$ satisfying
$$
\tag{$\dagger$}
\frac{\|f(x)-f(a)-\alpha(x-a)\|}{\|x-a\|}\to 0
$$
as $x\to a$. But in this case $f$ is itself linear: $f(x_1+x_2) = (x_1+x_2)^\intercal A = (x_1^{\intercal} +x_2^\intercal)A = x_1^{\intercal}A +x_2^{\intercal}A = f(x_1)+f(x_2)$, and similarly $f(\lambda.x) = \lambda.f(x)$. When $f$ is linear we can clearly take $\alpha=f$ to ensure that the numerator in $(\dagger)$ vanishes for all $x$, and hence certainly tends to $0$ as $x \to a$.
It follows that $Df_a = f$ that is, the linear map $x\mapsto x^{\intercal}A$.
If your textbook gives the derivative as $A^\intercal$ it is perhaps using some convention where it identifies $(\mathbb R^n)^*$ with $\mathbb R^n$ by taking transposes. If you do that, then $f$ becomes the map $f(x) = A^\intercal x$. See the addendum below for more on this.
However, there is another important point. The derivative $Df$ is, at each point where $f$ is differentiable, a linear map, thus the derivative $Df$ is a function $a\mapsto Df_a$ from $\mathbb R^n$ to the space of linear maps (i.e. matrices) and in the case of $f(x)=x^\intercal A$ that function is the constant function that assigns to every $a \in \mathbb R^n$ the linear map $x\mapsto x^{\intercal}A$. The same is true for any linear map $f\colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$: it is differentiable on all of $\mathbb R^n$ and its derivative $Df$ is the constant function from $\mathbb R^n$ to the space of linear maps from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$ which sends every vector in $\mathbb R^n$ to the same linear map, namely $f$ itself, that is $Df_a = f$ for all $a \in \mathbb R^n$.
Notice that with a little bit of thought you can see that this is consistent with the one-variable case. In the 1-d setting a linear map must be of the form $f(x)=c.x$, and $f$ has derivative $f'(x)=c$, a constant. The higher-dimensional theory says you should think of that constant as a linear map, (i.e. a 1x1 matrix) but since $1\times 1$ matrices are just real numbers the distinction is hard to notice in the one-dimensional case!
Addendum:
This section is prompted by Philipp's comment below. We give some more details on the identification of a linear map with a matrix and apply this process to the case of $f(x) = x^{\intercal}A$.
If $f\colon V \to W$ is a linear map between finite-dimensional vector spaces and $V$ has basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_m\}$ and $W$ has basis $\{f_1,\ldots, f_n\}$ then the matrix $A = (a_{ij})$ of $f$ is given by $f(e_j) = \sum_{i=1}^m a_{ij}f_i$, and if you identify $V$ with $\mathrm{Mat}_{m,1}$ and $W$ with $\mathrm{Mat}_{n,1}$ via $v\mapsto (c_i)^{\intercal}$ and $w \mapsto (d_i)^{\intercal}$, where $v = \sum_{i=1}^mc_i e_i\in V$ and $w = \sum_{j=1}^n d_i f_i\in W$, then the action of $f$ corrresponds to left-multiplication by $A = (a_{ij})$.
If you apply this to the case of $f(x)= x^\intercal A$, then $\mathbb R^n = \mathrm{Mat}_{n,1}$ has its "standard basis" $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$, and $(\mathbb R^n)^* = \mathrm{Mat}_{1,n}$ has a natural basis given by the transpose of this basis, $\{e_1^{\intercal},\ldots,e_n^{\intercal})$. Now these bases identify $\mathbb R^n$ with $\mathrm{Mat}_{n,1}$ (the map is just the identity map) and $(\mathbb R^n)^*$ with $\mathrm{Mat}_{n,1}$ where the map is the transpose map. The matrix of $f$ is then the map which corresponds to $f$ via these identifications, and it is $A^\intercal$.

Concerning your point: "[...] thus the derivative $Df$ is a function $a\mapsto Dfa$
from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to the space of linear maps (i.e. matrices) and in the case of $f(x)=x^⊺A$ that function is the constant function that assigns to every $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$
the linear map $x\mapsto x^⊺A$.[...]"   How does the matrix $Df_a$ look like in the case of $f(x)=x^TA$?

@Philipp I've appended an answer to this to my original post, as it got too long to be a comment!

If I carefully read the definition of total differentiability then it says that it only refers to functions that map between $\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. from one column vector space to another. This means that before talking about the derivative of $f(x)=x^TA$ we have to"convert" it accordingly. Either rigorosly by applying linear algebra like you did in you addendum or simply in a naive way which argues that it doesn't matter if vectors are oriented horizontally or vertically. I guess that this picks up the idea from @Ted Black's comment. Does this summary make sense to you?

@Philipp - what you say is not quite correct here. The definition of the total derivative makes sense for functions between (finite-dimensional) normed vector spaces as in the OP: if $X$ and $Y$ are vector spaces equipped with norms, then a function $f\colon X \to Y$ is differentiable at $a \in X$ if there is a linear map $L\colon X \to Y$ which satisfies the limit condition given above. If you want to compute $L = Df_a$ though, you find its matrix with respect to some bases of $X$ and $Y$, and this process by convention identifies $X$ with $\mathbb R^m$ and $Y$ with $\mathbb R^n$.

But in relation to the specific example of $f(x) = x^{\intercal}A$, you are absolutely correct, the map as defined goes from $n$-dimensional column vectors to $n$-dimensional row vectors, but you can switch the latter back to column vectors by composing with the transpose map to get $(\intercal \circ f) (x)= A^{\intercal}x$.

Let $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)^T,A=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&\cdots&a_{1n}\\\vdots&&\vdots\\a_{n1}&\cdots&a_{nn} \end{pmatrix}$.
Then, $$\begin{align*}
f(x)&=\mathbf{x}^TA\\
&=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&\cdots&a_{1n}\\\vdots&&\vdots\\a_{n1}&\cdots&a_{nn} \end{pmatrix}\\
&=(a_{11}x_1+\cdots+a_{n1}x_n,\ldots,a_{1n}x_1+\cdots+a_{nn}x_n)\\
\implies D f(\mathbf{x})&=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&\cdots&a_{n1}\\\vdots&&\vdots\\a_{1n}&\cdots&a_{nn} \end{pmatrix}\\
&=A^T
\end{align*}$$
So $A^T$ is indeed derivative of $f$.
For example, let $f(x,y)=(x,y)\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}=(x,x+y)$. So $Df=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1 \end{pmatrix}$.
The way how I inteperate this is just like the usual derivative of scalar valued functions with one variable. Let $f(x)=(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$, then for each $f_i$, take find their gradient $\nabla f_i$ which is a vector, then combine them together which gives you a matrix. However in this case, $A$ is a square matrix (special case), you can try a non-square matrix.
Note: $f(x)$ is a vector, so it is a vector-valued function, and thus its "derivative" is a matrix. You can look at this (page 22)
Please comment if there are any errors.
